# Playing QuakeLive on Mac?

Tags: macos, quake-live

Is there a way to play QuakeLive on a Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No more. Quake Live is now windows only.

Comment: i confirm this information. It works very well

Comment: me too! OMG THAT"S OSM WHY DIDN"T I KNOW ABT IT?? :(

Comment: @Mechko: O.O ` `

Comment: No more, QL now works outside of a browser and currently the client is windows-only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It works on a Intel Mac running Tiger. (10.4 or higher.)

Comment: Can you elaborate how to get it to work?

Comment: It is basically the plugin install, installed by dragging the plugin into the apps folder. And then the maps will download and you will be able to play.

Comment: k, sorry. The question sounded more complicated. :P

Comment: understandable, it's harder on PC.